# Please provide the best possible combination for the following situation...

Tags: permutations, combinations, gcd-and-lcm

I have a $39$ cm precious metal wire...
I need $22$ pieces of $14$ cm, $13$ pieces of $9.5$ cm, $10$ pieces of $24$ cm and $5$ pieces of $7$ cm.

> How should I make the best possible combinations of different sizes and units so that I have to buy the least number of $39$ cm wires.

Thanks in advance and best regards.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Show us what you've tried and where you are getting stuck. Do not just post a homework problem.

Comment: Ok. I am new here. It was a first time. Won't happen again. Regards.

Comment: You can [edit] the question to provide what @TedShifrin asks for.